# How To Get Multiple Background Images In One HTML Index File?

Tags: html, css

How to use HTML and CSS only to get multiple Background images using one index file and one CSS file only. I want to have a the second background to be a background video and a 3rd background to be another image.This is how my css html element looks like:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', "sans-serif";
  font-size: 120%;
  background-image: url(pictures/main-photo.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: darkslategrey;
  min-width: 1435px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean multiple backgrounds? At the same time? A "slideshow" type thing? Question needs some clarification.

Comment: background-image: url(xyz.gif), url(abc.gif);
background-position: right bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;

Answer (score 0):

You can use several `background-image` attributes with `background-position` to set where you want the images. You also want `background-repeat: no-repeat;`